# How to get details/log for a commit error in QGIS?

Tags: qgis

Lets take the following error as an example.

```
Commit errors: Could not commit changes to layer layername
```

and when clicking "Show more"

```
Could not commit changes to layer layername
Error: ERRORS: 3 features not added
```

[image]

Its hard to guess how to interpret this (is this a message generated by the server, or by the client, or maybe its a message from the server wrapped into a message by the client).

How can I get more details about why it fails? Perhaps a log file? Perhaps a log that I can open within QGIS?

I realize that the real problem might be on the server, but at least I would like to get more of those details/log events that must be available to QGIS.

In the example above, the layer is a WFS layer, hosted on a server that is out of my control. But I would as far as possible prefer an answer that generally explains how to interpret such errors, including getting more details.

Comment: In modern QGIS you can get a log of network traffic in the debug panel (F12), does that help? It might be the WFS server not providing more information.

Comment: On the bottom right of the QGIS main window there is a speech bubble icon that open the log message panel, have a look here to see if you get more info...

Comment: Thanks for both the tips :) I havent gotten the error again since writing, but I assume that both methods will provide more details.